# What is the best dropdown navigation alternative to Superfish?

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigation, mootools

I know superfish is amazing, but the terrible CMS we are using conflicts with it in IE6 (hovers break in IE6 when the CMS applies a selected class to the li). I don't know how, but feel free to look at [valitics.com/test1](http://valitics.com/test1). It can be mootools, scriptaculous, whatever, I just need a good alternative to superfish.

Answer (score 1):

Arian's http://mootools.net/forge/p/moodropmenu is quite straight forward. Checkout the newer version of moodropmenu on github.

A year ago I built one my own github.com/eerne/sushi-menu/ . It should work nicely on IE6+ and in css-only mode too. Tab should let you navigate through the menu (currently IE only).  Though it was written with MooTools 1.2.2 and I haven't tested it recently.

Looking at valitics.com/test1 I suppose whichever plugin you take, you will need to add some custom code.

> IE6 (hovers break in IE6 when the CMS
>   applies a selected class to the li)

This is just a guess, but it sound like some CSS issue that could be fixed with existing script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write something simple/elegant on your own with jquery?  Here's a good tutorial: http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html ... most of the tutorials only require a little bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

I use 
[OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu),
In my opinion it is easier and better than [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish).